# How exclude .json extension from nginx logs

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I wan to exclude logs for all these extensions `woff, jpg, jpeg, png, gif, ico, css, js, json`

in `default.conf` I added these location rule

```
location ~* \.(woff|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|json)$ {
        access_log off;
    }
```

all extensions was exluded from logs, except `json`

I tried separate rule like this

```
location ~* \.(json)$ {
        access_log off;
    }
```

or

```
location ~ \.json$ {
        access_log off;    
    }
```

any way I still can see json files in logs

in the same default.conf I have another rule for json extension

```
location ~* \.(json)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "must-revalidate";
    }
```

can this be the problem?
any idea how to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding `access_log off;` rule in first location for `json` extension

```
location ~* \.(json)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "must-revalidate";
        access_log off;
    }
```